# Token Based Authentication in Apache Zeppelin

Tags: apache, shiro, apache-zeppelin

Apache Zeppelin supports Shiro Authentication and We can write our custom class for Oauth2 authentication. But instead of asking username/password at time of login, I need to authenticate the user with a JWT token.

Is there a way to do the same?